# Automated data retrieval from website using POST not working due to http 405 error

Tags: python, ruby, perl, http-post, bots

I'm working on something similar to [*Automate data retrieval from a web site using a Ruby web bot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034915/automate-data-retrieval-from-a-web-site-using-a-ruby-web-bot) to automate a script to get the data from result website (submit a roll no and get the result).

I'm using Ruby here and using the POST method to submit the roll number and get the result page, but since the main target page which accepts the roll number is a .htm page, and due to which I'm ending up with

```
HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported
```

(most of the solutions for this issue suggest updates on server side which is not in my control) I would like to automate and get the results so as to create a dataset for data mining purposes.

I tried to research on how to get result page using an automated script but could not get anything satisfactory. Can anyone let me know how to achieve it, through any kind of script? The language doesn't matter for me since data collection is the target.

Any guidance to achieve this will be helpful.

I'm trying to extract results of 2007, from site

```
http://resultsarchives.nic.in/cbseresults/cbseresults2007/aieee/cbseaieee.htm
```

You can use sample roll number series 24800000 .. 24809999, say 24801002 is valid roll number (8 digits), to see how the result is displayed.

I have tagged the questions with different languages since I feel that solutions may exist in any of those languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I ca tell the site's [*Terms of Use*](http://www.nic.in/terms-use) don't prohibit programmed access, so I think you are okay with this.

It's a very simple job using Perl's [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) module.

It would look like this. Note that the output is just the text content of the HTML page, so ther are no line breaks. If you want the HTML itself instead then use `$mech->content` instead of `$mech->text`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use WWW::Mechanize;

my $url = 'http://resultsarchives.nic.in/cbseresults/cbseresults2007/aieee/cbseaieee.htm';

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

$mech->get($url);

$mech->submit_form( fields => { regno => 24809999 } );
print $mech->text, "\n";
```

**output**

```
 CBSE - ALL INDIA ENGINEERING / ARCHITECTURE ENTRANCE EXAMINATION 2007 http://cbseresults.nic.in      Examination Results 2007      Brought to you by National Informatics Centre    ALL INDIA ENGINEERING / ARCHITECTURE ENTRANCE EXAMINATION (AIEEE - 2007) Roll No: 24809999 Name: BHOSALE CHETAN ANIL Mother's Name: BHOSALE UJJVALA ANIL Father's Name: BHOSALE ANIL BHAGWANRAO Paper    Subjects    Marks ObtainedPaper-1 Physics, Chemistry & Mathematics -2 Paper-2 Mathematics & Aptitude Test Not Applicable/Not Applied   B.E./B.Tech  B.Arch All India Rank 539404 ------ State Rank( State code of eligibility : 21  ) 41736 ------  Remarks:  BTECH:   - Not Eligible for Central CounsellingBARCH:   -   Note:  For details on central counselling, Please visit http://ccb.nic.in or http://aieee.nic.in Cut off score for the purpose of counselling has been decided by Central Counselling Board.  State Ranks are based on State Code of Eligibility ie. State from where the candidate has passsed +2 examination. Those who have not filled up State Code of eligibility, their State rank has not been indicated. State rank is privisional subject to verification of documents at the time of counselling.  Disclaimer: Neither NIC nor CBSE is responsible for any inadvertent error that may have crept in the results being published on NET. The results published on net are for immediate information to the examinees. These cannot be treated as original Score card. Original Score cards shall be despatched by the Board.   Designed, Developed and Hosted by National Informatics Centre
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm :) :), it will be helpful for me to collect the data for my data mining project.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the requests that your browser makes when using that website, you'll see that a POST request is sent to:

```
http://resultsarchives.nic.in/cbseresults/cbseresults2007/aieee/cbseaieee.asp
```

With the data:

```
regno: 24801002
```

You can target this URL to scrape the website (if it's allowed).

Comment: its not allowed , if i target the .asp link with post method it sends the page with access denied :( , is there any other way out ?